# Which width and height is best for 16:9 aspect ratio on VGA level?

Tags: android, resolution

As we know, the resolution of VGA is 640×480 and the aspect ratio is 4:3. But if I want to get the resolution about the 16:9 aspect ratio on VGA level, how to calculate it?

Is there any rule to get the right value?

Comment: What are you asking for?  16000 metres by 9000 metres is 16:9.

Comment: I think you could not get width or height only on the base of aspect ratio.

Comment: @Siddiqui I have some special requirements about the 16:9. The 4:3 is the original aspect ratio. And I have to change the resolution for 16:9.

Comment: If we consider 640 is the width of the screen then the resolution at 16:9 is 640x360.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the way to figure out the aspect is like this:

```
ClippedWidth = ScreenWidth
ClippedHeight = 9 * ScreenWidth / 16
```

For VGA, that comes out at `640 x 360`.

If it were to come out larger than the actual screen height then you need to reverse the formula:

```
ClippedWidth = 16 * ScreenHeight / 9
ClippedHeight = ScreenHeight
```

Note that I have assumed you are trying to fit 16:9 data into 4:3.  It's easy to go the other way.  In fact, you don't even need the aspect:

```
ClippedHeight = SourceHeight * ScreenWidth / SourceWidth
```

or

```
ClippedWidth = SourceWidth * ScreenHeight / SourceHeight
```

In all cases, these calculations maintain the concept of square pixels.

Comment: I can understand the situation-1. But the situation-2...could you please take some examples. Thanks very much!

Comment: This is just a generalisation.  For example, if you have a window that can be arbitrarily resized, you need to handle both cases.  It might not happen in your case, but it doesn't hurt to make it solid.